# Some answers never get feedback?

Tags: discussion

Every now and then I see an old question, where I think someone actually provided the right answer, but the OP did not give it a green tick nor a comment. What shall be done in this case? Flag the question? For what reasoning? It is really annoying when I personally take some effort to answer some question but I don't even get a textual feedback whether my answer was helpful or not.

Comment: If you are sure the answer is correct or helpful, you can upvote. No one can do anything on behalf of the questioner

Comment: The accept mark is meaningless in the grand scheme of things. All it means is that it was the one the asker decided to click the green check mark for. Upvotes are much more meaningful as far as usefulness is concerned.

Comment: There is no point in flagging; moderators can't mark answers as accepted, nor can we force the OP to do so. There is *no requirement* to vote or mark answers as accepted.

Comment: You'll learn to spot the folks who are more likely to do this.  Usually, they've made the least amount of effort when asking (poor formatting, not enough details, missing exceptions, missing or sloppy code, etc).  I'm prone to comment first, so I get a sense from how fast and well they respond as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accepting an answer is not forced and textual feedback like "thank you", "it's working" and similar are not welcome, if op thinks that a post is best worked for him/her then he/she can accept or upvote or do both it's his/her vote. what other user can do is to upvote or downvote as depends on post.

From [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers):

> Accepting an answer is not mandatory; do not feel compelled to accept
>   the first answer you receive. Wait until you receive an answer that
>   answers your question well.
>
> Please do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say
>   "Thank you". Comments are meant for requesting clarification, leaving
>   constructive criticism, or adding relevant but minor additional
>   information – not for socializing. If you want to say "thank you,"
>   vote on or accept that person's answer, or simply pay it forward by
>   providing a great answer to someone else's question.