# Should one accept an answer if he doesn't need it anymore?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

Suppose I am working on developing code, encounter a problem, and ask a question on Stack Overflow. No one answers my question, so I decided to write the code a different way.

Later, I get an answer to my question, but it is hard for me to say if it works or not, since I'm not using the same code anymore.

Should I accept this answer?

Comment: It is up to you. There is no obligation to do so. If you think the answer is useful, give it an up vote, if you feel it is not useful, down vote. If the answer helped you, accept it. Don't feel pressured to take any action at all. Optionally you might leave a comment.

Comment: Also related, not a dupe: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344957/578411

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As rene said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354258/should-one-accept-an-answer-if-he-doesnt-need-it-anymore#comment499583_354258), it is up to you.

The accept mark means one thing, and one thing only: the person who asked this question found this answer to be the *most useful* of all the answers.

If you want to send that message to future readers of the question, then you should accept the answer. If not, then don't accept it.

Again, as rene said, don't feel pressured to accept an answer just because someone wrote it. You can thank them for the answer with an upvote, as can all other members of the community. An accept is kind of something special, and if you don't think you're in a position to judge which answer is the most useful, then you probably shouldn't be accepting it.

> ...so I decided to write the code a different way.

That makes me think you should write an answer of your own, presenting the alternative, explaining why you chose it, and giving either your code (if possible) or at least a sketch of the implementation (if you don't want to license the actual code under CC by-SA).

Clearly, *that* answer would have been the most useful to you, since it's the path you ultimately took, and you would probably want to accept it. (You'll have to wait a few days after posting it, though, because the system won't let you immediately accept a self-answer. There's nothing wrong with self-answering, though.)