# Highest upvoted answer is after accepted answer

Tags: bug, answers, accepted-answer, sorting

In the following Question, I don't understand the answers Order :

[Handle file download from ajax post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086162/handle-file-download-from-ajax-post/16086435#16086435)

As said in this meta answer : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283467/903840, 
the most upvoted answer should be on top but it isn't

Comment: The Meta post you linked to is a **feature request**, one that hasn't been implemented yet and where [the post it's a duplicate of](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326095/please-unpin-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top) was **declined**.

Comment: This is by design, the OP accepted the answer as the best fitting one to answer his question, but it doesn't have to be the most upvoted one at the same time.

Answer (score 13):

*It's not a bug, it's a feature.*
Accepted answers always get priority sorting.

That's one of the perks of the answer being "accepted". It's a marker that says the answer worked for the OP, and as such, indicates it may work for users that have the same problem.

That said, **always look at votes**. The accepted answer isn't necessarily the "best" answer.

Comment: "It's not a bug, it's a feature" I love that quote.

Comment: So accepted answers *do* have perks? This counteracts the *other* common statement that "accepting an answer is fully optional, it doesn't really mean anything, it doesn't change a thing in the status of the question" etc.(I would also have added "isn't guaranteed to work" if you did not mention that already.) But even the worst possible *accepted* answer ... always comes out on top.

Comment: @chade_ The first time someone calls you a horse you punch them on the nose. The second time someone calls you a horse you call them a jerk. The third time someone calls you a horse... well maybe then it's time to start shopping for a saddle. -> This horse got it's saddle a long time ago.

Comment: @usr2564301: Where does SO say that accepting an answer is as meaningless as you claim it is? Accepting an answer is the way to express that a certain answer worked for the OP. It also has a significant rep reward for the answer's author...

Comment: @Cerbrus: the community is extremely schizophrenic about this. Here is one opposite end; the other end is "In the end **only the up and down votes are important**. Those are the real measures for your post quality."  (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/313216) "The accept mark means **one thing, and one thing only**: the person who asked this question found this answer to be the most useful of all the answers." (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/354260) ".. worked best for the asker, but I don't think their vote should **override the community**." (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253754)

Comment: @usr2564301: schizophrenic? Divided, maybe. But those are some older links and some feature requests. Nothing I said about accepted answers is news to you, it's just how the site works right now. The sorting and +15 rep are simply part of the "accept". There's nothing open to interpretation on that. Sure, there are requests to change how that works, but those ___requests___ aren't relevant here.

Comment: Personally I'd say *"It's not a bug, it's a misfeature."* But, as other comments note, the community is divided about this.

Answer (score -2):

Reading the comments, I understand this is a feature ... for now.
My actual concern is there are very old questions which are still accurate but the answer is not accurate anymore, technology changed and new solutions arrive.

The algorithm should take care of the accepted answer *date* and balances it with a bunch of upvoted dates. For example, probably a bad guess, if there are 100 upvote on another answer 6 month after the accepted answer, then order it up.

You have also to deal with upvote on the accepted answer that can still come this late.

Comment: thanks for downvote ... I understand there are very uncomprehensive people. I understand "requests" aren't relevant here